# How does this bash statemnet test ".$TOMCAT_USER" = . && TOMCAT_USER=tomcat work?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to understand the tomcat daemon.sh script which contains a bunch of lines along the lines `test ".$TOMCAT_USER" = . && TOMCAT_USER=tomcat`

I figured out that `test ".$TOMCAT_USER" = . && TOMCAT_USER=tomcat` checks if an environment variable TOMCAT_USER is already defined if so it uses it and if not it uses the default value of tomcat

What I understand is the how the statement is evaluated by bash.

Comment: `&&` it's Boolean, means if first statement is successfully run (means exit status code is zero ) then run another statement. you can run script in debug mode to understand like `bash -x scriptname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` is a logical "and"; essentially, it lets you do something based on whether the previous command completed successfully (although this might not be true in more complex cases, for example, consider `true || false && echo true`, here's [an article on on boolean logic rules](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_4/chpt_7/5.html)). Another way of writing the statement in your question would be:

```
if test ".$TOMCAT_USER" = .; then
    TOMCAT_USER=tomcat
fi
```

This is a strange way of testing for an unset/null variable, though. POSIX already has multiple ways to do that:

```
: "${TOMCAT_USER:=tomcat}"  # Assign as part of the expansion,
                            # `:' is a noop to avoid running the expansion.
TOMCAT_USER="${TOMCAT_USER:-tomcat}"  # Expand, and then assign
```

The difference between the `:=`/`:-` and `:`-less versions are that the `:` versions also test if the variable is null in addition to testing if it is unset (which is closer to your original test).